# Inserting values based on unique values of another table(Normalization)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have Table1 with columns A,B & C.
I want to create Table 2 and create Primary Key for values in ColumnA, Table1(unique), and then accordingly populate values B and C from Table1 (based on unique values of Column A).

Any help will be appreciated. 
EDIT:I am using SQL server and tried using INSERT INTO...SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server, Try this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColumnA ORDER BY ColumnA),
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC
        FROM YourTable
)
INSERT INTO Table2
(
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC
)
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting an error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 136
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Comment: what is the exact query that you are using ?

Comment: I used the same query as you have suggested. Except there are 7 columns instead of 3

Comment: the error is on the order by part, so you might have missed some space or something before or after that order by. please check